# How can you sort a data frame by number of non zero entries using python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I have a data frame like this:

| a | b | c | d | e |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a_1 | b_1 | c_1 | d_1 | e_1 |
| 0 | b_2 | c_2 | d_2 | e_2 |
| 0 | b_3 | c_3 | 0 | e_3 |
| 0 | 0 | c_4 | 0 | e_4 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | e_5 |

I want the data frame to look like this:

| e | c | b | d | a |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| e_1 | c_1 | b_1 | d_1 | a_1 |
| e_2 | c_2 | b_2 | d_2 | 0 |
| e_3 | c_3 | b_3 | 0 | 0 |
| e_4 | c_4 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| e_5 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

where "letter_number" is any value not equal to 0.

Answer (score 2):

#### pandas >= 1.1

We can call `sort_index` on the columns with a custom `key` function:

```
df.sort_index(key=lambda c: df[c].ne('0').sum(), ascending=False, axis=1)

     e    c    b    d    a
0  e_1  c_1  b_1  d_1  a_1
1  e_2  c_2  b_2  d_2    0
2  e_3  c_3  b_3    0    0
3  e_4  c_4    0    0    0
4  e_5    0    0    0    0
```

I assumed the zeroes are in string format and not numeric.

---

#### Older versions

We can sort the column headers based on the predicate you described using python's inbuilt `sorted` function:

```
df[sorted(df, key=lambda c: df[c].ne('0').sum(), reverse=True)]

     e    c    b    d    a
0  e_1  c_1  b_1  d_1  a_1
1  e_2  c_2  b_2  d_2    0
2  e_3  c_3  b_3    0    0
3  e_4  c_4    0    0    0
4  e_5    0    0    0    0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try with `np.argsort` and `iloc`:

```
df.iloc[:, np.argsort(df.eq('0').sum())]
```

Or use `sort_values`:

```
df[df.eq('0').sum().sort_values().index]
```

Both give:

```
     e    c    b    d    a
0  e_1  c_1  b_1  d_1  a_1
1  e_2  c_2  b_2  d_2    0
2  e_3  c_3  b_3    0    0
3  e_4  c_4    0    0    0
4  e_5    0    0    0    0
```